# Treeview weirdly growing over time

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

My code creates a treeview inside a frame to display data from a dictionary.

```py
# frame into which to place Tree view 
info_post_frame = tk.Frame()

# creating Tree view widget
tree = tk.ttk.Treeview(info_post_frame, height=0)
tree["columns"] = ("A","B","C","D")
tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch='NO')
tree.column("A", anchor='w', width=60)
tree.column("B", anchor='w', width=60)
tree.column("C", anchor='w', width=60)
tree.column("D", anchor='w', width=60)

tree.heading("#0", text="")
tree.heading("A", text="Book", anchor='w')
tree.heading("B", text="Level", anchor='w')
tree.heading("C", text="Type", anchor='w')
tree.heading("D", text="Page", anchor='w')
tree.pack()
```

By pressing a button on the Tkinter window, the dictionary clears and updates with values from a .xlsx file.

```py
status = {}
global status
status.clear()
----code to update dictionary----
```

This dictionary then populates the treeview with its data with the following function.

```py
def view_status():
    #clear the Tree view
    for item in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(item)

    #populate the Tree view
    for item in status.keys():
        # insert correct data into Tree view
        tree.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=count,text='',values=(status[item][0],status[item][1],status[item][4],status[item][7]))
        count=count+1
    tree.configure(height=count)
```

After every use of the button, the treeview expands in width by a few pixels or so. After 5 - 10 uses it creeps out of my TKinter window geometry bounds.

This image shows the original state:

[image]

This image shows the final state after 10 uses:

[image]

I've tried using `(fill='both', expand=True)`, placing the treeview directly into the root window, and removing the height argument.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `stretch='NO'` to each treeview column seems to work.

```
tree["columns"] = ("A","B","C","D")
tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch='NO')
tree.column("A", anchor='w', width=60, stretch='NO')
tree.column("B", anchor='w', width=60, stretch='NO')
tree.column("C", anchor='w', width=60, stretch='NO')
tree.column("D", anchor='w', width=40, stretch='NO')
```